# nginx access_log off not working

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx site config like this. I want all location to log into access_log, except the ones mentioned in the config. However this config does log all **/event/lp** urls into access log. Am I missing something?

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/sub.example.com.log all;
    server_name sub.example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;

    proxy_set_header   Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;

    client_max_body_size       20m;
    client_body_buffer_size    128k;

    proxy_connect_timeout      900;
    proxy_send_timeout         900;
    proxy_read_timeout         900;

    proxy_buffer_size          32k;
    proxy_buffers              4 32k;

    location ~ ^/event/ws {
        access_log off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_buffering    off;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_pass         http://pushstream_subscriber_support;
        break;
    }

    location ~ ^/event/lp {
        proxy_buffering    off;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        access_log         off;

        proxy_pass         http://pushstream_subscriber_support;
        post_action @update_visit_expire;
        break;
    }

    location ~ ^/event/ {
        access_log off;
        proxy_buffering    off;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_pass         http://pushstream_subscriber_support;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you restarted nginx?

Comment: Yes, multiple times, also reload...